# Should I use piping or redirection for input to 'sort'

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, sort

I want to do

```
awk -F "," '{print $1 }' inputfile1.txt | sort -u > distinctOutput.txt
```

Is this good performance-wise ? Or should I redirect / use a temp file since I think it is better to make sort wait till awk is done dumping the complete output? Or is this taken care internally?

(AIX 6.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `sort` uses temporary files automatically. Temproaries are mentioned in several places in the [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1.html) and [`info`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation) pages for `sort`, including:

```
   --compress-program=PROG
          compress temporaries with PROG; decompress them with PROG -d
   -T, --temporary-directory=DIR
          use  DIR  for temporaries, not $TMPDIR or /tmp; multiple options
          specify multiple directories
```

> If the environment variable TMPDIR is set, sort uses its value as the directory for temporary files instead of /tmp. The --temporary-directory (-T) option in turn overrides the environment variable.

---

To test, I ran:

```
base64 < /dev/urandom | sort
```

The memory usage of `base64` and `sort` stabilised quickly (`top -bn1 | grep 'base64|sort'`):

```
21877 root      20   0   11.1m   0.6m   0.5m R  63.9  0.0   7:23.46 base64
21878 root      20   0   21.4m   8.2m   0.8m R  31.9  0.4   4:44.15 sort
```

And I could see hundreds of temporary files in `/tmp` called `sortXXXXXX`:

```
$ ls /tmp/sort* | head
/tmp/sort03IIcQ
/tmp/sort052vXK
/tmp/sort07ZCcO
/tmp/sort09yrTN
/tmp/sort0anX08
/tmp/sort0BruPR
/tmp/sort0EgCYY
/tmp/sort0GsbQs
/tmp/sort0hCMDD
/tmp/sort0hdSMT
$ ls /tmp | grep -c sort
1990
```

So, I'd say you needn't worry about temporary files with `sort`. The best thing you can do is ensure that the location of the temporaries is on a fast filesystem (an SSD, or `tmpfs`, etc.).

#### DISCLAIMER: I have only considered GNU sort.

---

While the above analysis would apply only to GNU sort, the [AIX `sort`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sort.htm) also uses temporary files, or at least a directory for temporary files, according to the linked manual. I don't have an AIX system handy to test it.

[POSIX](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1posix.html) does not mention temporary files, so this is not a given.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention it is AIX 6.1. Does it make a difference which unix implemetation?

Comment: @dbza yes, usually. Since POSIX does not specify this behaviour, it is implementation dependent. If you have the GNU utilities, then no. AIX sort should use temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the behavoir with a huge file (comma separated, csv, 2173762 lines, 186MB)

`awk` piped to `sort` gives me, 49611 syscalls and:

```
real    0m5.134s
user    0m5.048s
sys     0m0.080s
```

`awk` to a temporary file and then `sort` the file in a 2nd step gives me 49719 syscalls and:

```
real    0m6.006s
user    0m5.836s
sys     0m0.152s
```

Even the other way, `sort` (`sort -k1 -u`) first and pipe to `awk` give me a worser result (47533 syscalls):

```
real    0m17.937s
user    0m17.565s
sys     0m0.348s
```

**Conclusion**: It seems you already found the most ressource-friendly method, or I can't find a faster one.

- awk: `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan`
- sort: `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13`